# Add namespace to a existing node of xml in php dom

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have this:

```
<user>
     <!-- data here -->
</user>
```

I want this:

```
<namespace:user>
    <!-- data here -->
</namespace:user>
```

I have tried to set `$prefix` attribute of `user` DomnNode. But it has no effect. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change, it. You will have to replace the elements. To this you would need all element nodes (or the nodes you want to change):

`$xpath->evaluate('//*')`

Evaluate return the nodes in document order. That mean we get parent nodes before their children. Convert the list into an array and reverse it.

`$nodes = array_reverse(iterator_to_array($xpath->evaluate('//*')));`

Now for each element create a replacement in the target namespace

`$replacement = $dom->createElementNS('urn:foo', 'foo:'.$node->localName);`

Get all child and attribute nodes and append them to the replacement:

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('node()|@*', $node) as $childNode) {
  $replacement->appendChild($childNode);
}
```

Last, replace the original node with the new one:

`$node->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $node);`

Full example:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<user id="abc">
  <name>username</name>
  <!-- comment -->
</user>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$nodes = array_reverse(
  iterator_to_array(
    $xpath->evaluate('//*')
  )
);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $replacement = $dom->createElementNS('urn:foo', 'foo:'.$node->localName);
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('node()|@*', $node) as $childNode) {
    $replacement->appendChild($childNode);
  }
  $node->parentNode->replaceChild($replacement, $node);
}

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo:user xmlns:foo="urn:foo" id="abc">
  <foo:name>username</foo:name>
  <!-- comment -->
</foo:user>
```